# Is it possible to execute tests in parallel with Slim engine?

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I use FitNesse with the SLIM engine to execute my tests. Since the test suites have since become quite large I have to start thinking about parallelization. Is it possible with FitNesse to execute tests in parallel? I know that the tests can be started from the command line and executed in parallel with `xargs` or `make`. However, I am looking for an easy (suited for non-developers) way that would for example be integrated in the FitNesse frontend. How can I do this?

Comment: you can do that in a different way, you can create multiple lists of the tests you want to execute and the use the command line interface (using the -c option). in this way you can start as many execution threads you want.

Comment: If command line is an option i can give you more details.

Comment: @alinoz Thanks for getting back to me. Command line currently is not an option. I need a solution that's feasible for non-technical users, preferably available via the FitNesse frontend itself.

Comment: @valentin if this is possible in Command line it means you can create an intermediate UI program (WPF for ex) to find all FitNesses and make it easy for users to parallelize.

Comment: @alinoz This is very interesing putting all details in StackOverflow so everyone car view it. As I found it's not parallel by design, it's by launching multiple instances right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to run a single Suite using multiple threads from the front-end. But have you tried just running multiple Tests (or Suites) via multiple tabs or browser windows?

Comment: +1 for a simple yet interesting idea. I tried it and it actually works. Thanks